# favicon not working in chrome (SFCC)

Tags: images, favicon

The fav icon on our site is not showing up in chrome or opera but is working well in firefox.

The code:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="${URLUtils.staticURL('/images/favicons/dyn-favicon.ico')}" />`

I've tried clearing the cache, using incognito, a different staticURL image, a different permanent image URL, and encoding the image in base64.  Each time, it works on firefox but on chrome the only fave icon i see is:

[image: image of a power button symbol in place of the favicon]

which is not the fav icon i'm looking for.

Also, I've inspected the page itself and the image does seem to be present, despite the not appearing.
[image]

Comment: It is not community

Answer (score 1):

The issue in our code based turned out to be related to a GTM tag which was overwriting other parts of the code when placed beforehand.  Moving the GTM tag resolved the issue.